# ModalViewController not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

After a long period of trying and searching the Internet and StackOverflow I could not find the answer I need.
My Problem is a warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <PAPasscodeViewController: 0x81cc8a0> on <ServerViewController: 0x75864b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am using a Custom Control called "PAPasscodeViewController", the thing itself is working but when I try to display the view on the ApplicationDidBecomeActive method it displays this warning in the Consoleoutput.
I am using this method to keep track of the Notification:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(wait)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

my `-(void)wait` is containing this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    NSLog(@"waiting");
    [self performSelector:@selector(enterPasscode) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3f];
```

The App is having a RootViewController and a GeneralViewController, if the User already downloaded a Config package the GeneralViewController gets pushed in after starting as a modalView like this (in the `viewDidLoad`):

```
GeneralView = [[GeneralViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeneralViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        GeneralView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:GeneralView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the GeneralView the User has more Options to open new Views through Buttons and they get pushed in through IBActions like the GeneralViewController.

So the Problem is occuring when this happens:

I am starting the App, Config Package was already installed and the User wants to track his ServerData on "ServerViewController", so he touches the appropriate Button for this.
Then the View gets pushed in (its now RootViewController (managed by AppDelegate)-> GeneralViewController(pushed in)-> ServerViewController(pushed in)), everything works fine.
Now when the User goes back to his Homescreen I am closing the modal View "ServerViewController" as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(close:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];}

-(IBAction)close:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

so when the App enters Backgrounding the ServerViewController gets dismissed, after resuming the App the GeneralViewController is now the active View Controller, and in his `-(void)viewDidAppear` I am calling the `-(void)wait` from above, it calls this function:

```
- (void)enterPasscode{
    PAPasscodeViewController *passcodeViewController = [[PAPasscodeViewController alloc] initForAction:PasscodeActionEnter];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        passcodeViewController.backgroundView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    passcodeViewController.delegate = self;
    passcodeViewController.passcode = [configArray objectAtIndex:3];
    passcodeViewController.simple = YES;
    [self presentViewController:passcodeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is working fine but then I am getting the annoying warning from above (here again so you dont have to scroll up)

```
Warning: Attempt to present <PAPasscodeViewController: 0x75d1c10> on <ServerViewController: 0x818b390> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

actually this is confusing because I think my GeneralViewController is now the Active ViewController again...
Maybe I am just blinded by the simplicity of this Problem... but maybe someone here can help me understand.
I did NOT find any solution in any other post here in StackOverflow or other sites concerning that exact problem!

Comment: You need some debug. The view controller that is calling presentViewController is not the top view controller, that's the problem. You need to discover why (posting the whole code - maybe on another site - would be helpful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove self as observer when your ServerViewController is not shown. Add the following code to ServerViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```